# How do I get my app folder on gradle 4?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I used to do this to name my apk:

```
outputFileName = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "apk/myapk.apk")
```

And now it is complaining about `output.outputFile.parent`. So what is the correct way to fix this?

I followed the steps on the migration guidelines but that put the apk on some other directory. I want it on `app/apk/`

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output)

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName =   "${variant.dirName}" +"${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
            println (output.outputFile.parent)
        }
}
```

Apk out dir is `/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/`.

More information on migration guide

> However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times.

**EDIT**
To get `.apk` in `app/apk` Do in `gradle file`

```
def path = "../../../../../app/apk/"
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        outputFileName = new File( path +  "${variant.dirName}" +"${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk")
        println (output.outputFile.parent)
    }
```

}

Apk out dir is `/app/apk/`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want the apk to go into /app/apk/. I guess maybe I can use `..` a few times to get back from the outputs dir?

Comment: Just a slight modification but that worked. Thanks. The modification was this `def path = "../../../app/apk/"` because it went a little too far on the `..`